# IAsyncOperation "Completed" handler race conditions?

Tags: winapi, windows-runtime, winrt-async

The `IAsyncOperation<TResult>` interface exposes a `Completed` property, which users can attach methods to that are invoked when the operation completes.

MS has [example code online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/handle-events#delegate-types-for-asynchronous-actions-and-operations) that illustrates the usage (I've trimmed it down for the purposes of this question):

```
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Web.Syndication.h>

using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::Web::Syndication;

void ProcessFeedAsync()
{
    Uri rssFeedUri{ L"https://blogs.windows.com/feed" };
    SyndicationClient syndicationClient;

    auto async_op_with_progress = syndicationClient.RetrieveFeedAsync(rssFeedUri);
    async_op_with_progress.Completed(
        [](
            IAsyncOperationWithProgress<SyndicationFeed,
            RetrievalProgress> const& sender,
            AsyncStatus const /* asyncStatus */)
        {
            SyndicationFeed syndicationFeed = sender.GetResults();
            // use syndicationFeed;
        });
}
```

The intended usage pattern seems to be:

1. Invoke the asynchronous operation
2. Capture the operation token into a local variable
3. Attach a completion function (here a C++ lambda) to the "Completed" property.

Are there any safeguards against the race condition where the asynchronous operation completes sometime after step 1 but before step 3? It's unlikely to happen with the provided example, because it's fetching something from the internet, but there are plenty of SDK calls that simply queue up data and return very quickly.

Simply guarding the `Completed` assignment with a check for `Status() != AsyncStatus::Completed` narrows the race-condition window but doesn't fundamentally fix the issue, if one actually exists. (e.g. If `IAsyncOperation` is guaranteed to call the handler immediately at `Completed`-assignment-time if the operation has already completed, then there's no issue).

The C++/WinRT C++17 projection does include support for native coroutines, but the programming model I'm locked into can't support that technique, and I have to use the `Completed` property. (Also, my example is C++/WinRT but it seems like this exists in the C# projection as well?)

Comment: "If IAsyncOperation is guaranteed to call the handler immediately at Completed-assignment-time if the operation has already completed, then there's no issue)." This. Though not necessarily "immediately"; it is allowed to defer the call (for example if the object has a policy that it always completes on a specific thread, then it may have to wait a little bit before it can get to that thread), but the call will eventually happen.

Comment: Wow, a great answer straight from the source! Thanks for responding so quickly with that detail :) I suspected there was a provision for this and that I was misunderstanding it, so I also filed a documentation clarification request over on GitHub: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/winrt-api/issues/2455

Comment: Also, sorry to pester, but if you feel motivated enough to repost your comment as an "answer" I'd be happy to accept it; standalone accepted answers are often more discoverable. Finally, thanks so much for decades of your blog; I've been a stalwart reader for my entire career :)

Comment: I've made a note to myself to add this to the docs when I have time. (Note that this behavior matches JS Promises and C# Tasks.) You are welcome to post your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synthesized answer and explanation from Raymond Chen's comment:

If the user attaches a method to the `Completed` property after the `IAsyncOperation` has already completed, the attached method will still be called. There are no guarantees about *when* it will be called, based on policies adhered to by the object (and probably things like the apartment model). It may be immediate, or it may be in the future, but the method will eventually be scheduled for execution.